# POWERQUERY : Iterate on a source n times because of a limit

Tags: powerquery

I need to gather elements calling an API with protocol http.
I am able to get the result, but the API can't return more than 100 results at each call

For this exemple, here is my step where we can see that I could have 3837 elements (total_count)  but only 100 elements are returned (limit). The offset can be use to start at a different element of the 3837 elements
Notice that I can force the limit, but I can't have a value bigger than 100

[image]

Finaly, I would like to have a loop that can call x times the http (39 times for this exemple) by increasing each time the offset and reconciliate the 39 results in one table

Would you have some tips to help me with this problem ? Can we do some kind of loop ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `List.Generate` to create and then execute your calls.  For the delays, take a look at Chris Webb's blog about using [`Function.InvokeAfter`](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/04/30/using-function-invokeafter-in-power-query/) and also some of the discussion on that blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet I used with the Jira API. You should be able to get the gist from it.

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(yourJiraInstance, [Query=[maxResults="100",startAt="0"]])),
totalIssuesCount = Source[total],

// Now it is time to build a list of startAt values, starting on 0, incrementing 100 per item
startAtList = List.Generate(()=>0, each _ < totalIssuesCount, each _ +100),
urlList = List.Transform(startAtList, each Json.Document(Web.Contents(yourJiraInstance, [Query=[maxResults="100",startAt=Text.From(_)]]))),
```

This came from Nick Cerneaz (and Tiago Machado) from their posts on [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-Integrations/All-data-not-displayed-in-Power-BI-from-Jira/qaq-p/723117).

Comment: ok i bow to the power of powerquery. Thanks. My need is to extract from Redmine instead of Jira but it works the same. Perfect !